# How do I get around the 403 response code that a Browser gives me?

Tags: java, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

I am writing a webcrawer type program and along with html, I need to download the images, swf's etc to make it available offline.

Someone provided some really useful information earlier, on downloading files:

```
import static org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile;
public static void Download() {

    URL dl = null;
    File fl = null;
    try {
        fl = new File(System.getProperty("user.home").replace("\\", "/") + "/Desktop/Screenshots.zip");
        dl = new URL("http://example.com/uploads/Screenshots.zip");
        copyURLToFile(dl, fl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

which works really well, however, some sites give me a 403 block. After doing some research I see that it is largely an attempt by websites to restrict bots from downloading. Is there a workaround for this in Java? Apparently you need to send it as an HTTP request rather than use the code that I have.

A link that isn't working for me as an example is : http://images.4chan.org/v/src/1340901798824.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 403 means Forbidden, that should give you a hint on what's going on, no?

Comment: _an attempt by websites to restrict bots from downloading_... yep, websites don't want you doing what you're doing.

Comment: See http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E403.html for an explanation of 403

Comment: Yeah, I know.... Man so annoying, I've seen that there is a workaround in c#, and wondered whether there might be one in java too?

Comment: Additionally, that file gives a `404 File not found` if you copy the link in your browser's address bar. Which isn't exactly a `403`.

Comment: @MattMarx What about the word "Forbidden" don't you understand?

Comment: Yep I get that its forbidden. But I'm not using it to make money or profit, its just for personal use. Basically what I want to use the program for is to be able to enter a search criteria say for example, 'java tutorial', and then it downloads the top 5 sites relevant to my search...

Comment: Even so.  If these websites have an approved API, use that, otherwise...we're not going to help you try to get around legitimate websites' perfectly reasonable restrictions.

Comment: You see, SO is populated by professional developers who implement sites enforcing such policies much more than with the l33t crowd trying to deface our work.

Comment: Hey guys sorry for the offence, I'm still at Uni and hope too to be a professional developer when I finish, I mean it as no insult to you or anyone else's work, just looking to do something cool in my freetime.

Comment: Why do you want to replicate what the major search engines have already done?  Do you hope to recreate, as a single developer, the efforts of thousands of people over 15 years?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP code 403 means `FORBIDDEN`.

You cannot get around this restriction without providing authentication credentials, which you do not have.

Skip those pages and move on.